# why is my simple node Service returning views.exposed_data

Tags: 7, views, services

my simple Services endpoint uses the `Views 3` & `JSON data document` settings in this screenshot:

[image]
[image]

at least a few days ago the structure was simply...

```
{}{
"nodes": [{node:{},..],
"view": {
"name": "biz_locations",
"display": "page_1",
"path": "locations.json",
"root": "nodes",
"child": "node",
"pages": 9,
"page": 0,
"count": 173,
"limit": 20,
}
}
```

now all of the sudden it's including these three HUGE arrays:

```
"exposed_data": {BIG OBJECT},
"exposed_raw_input": {BIG OBJECT},
"filter": {BIG OBJECT}
```

with way more than I need or want to return. I don't know what I've changed to having Services include these. The `Simple` setting is the generally structure I want, but only with the first set of json properties above.

**Is there a place you can defined / add your own JSON data format?** or **how can i remove the large exposed_data, exposed_raw_input, and filter properties in Drupal's administration?**

Comment: Are you using DrupalGap?

Comment: @tyler, just the Services endpoint. none of the JS

Comment: If you are using DrupalGap, it appends that data onto the results so it knows how to render Views Exposed Filters. Please create an issue that requests some type of configuration to control this output within DrupalGap, and then we can see to its resolution.

Comment: @tyler.frankenstein, i created the issue as a Feature Request here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2446513

Comment: @tyler.frankenstein, the only reference to exposed_raw_input in the DrupalGap module code is commented out. I don't see how DrupalGap is playing any part in this. Do you know a safe hook to remove these properties from the response without breaking any depending code?

Comment: `hook_preprocess_views_views_json_style_simple()`